# Advantage of using emitted output properties over viewchild in angular

Tags: angular

```
//first approach importing the child component and accessing its properties 

import { childComponent}  from './childdetail.component';
@Component({
  selector: "testProject",
  templateUrl: "app/partials/Main.html"
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild(childComponent) childDetail:childDetailComponent;
  this.getChildProperty(this.childDetail.shipment)

  getChildProperty(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}



//second approach include getChildProperty method in ts file
//child component will have an eventEmitter that emits shipment value
// view will look like below code

<child-component (shipmentValue)="getChildProperty($event)">
```

Which of the two is a better approach and why? I am confused as to which approach is best as I can achieve my end-goal with both. Any explanation will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Events keep your components decoupled (you wouldn't need the parent to know the specific type of the child inside the component).

Answer (score 1):

the linked article will give you some direction:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/

Most of time event emitters and the simple interaction between components are desired for readability and modularity of the code base. Use viewchild when you need to inject a reference to the component.

Comment: @Gift could you accept the answer? if no further question